# Get information about OS Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

What syscalls i can use that get information about OS Linux? I new in assembler. I write code on nasm.

I have to get the most detailed information about the OS type, version and other information. I know that there is some information in the system files, but I do not understand how to get this information using system calls.

Comment: Check the `uname` system call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command `dmidecode` with option `--type` to see info that you want.

**Example**:

- To see Memory info, run one of these commands:

```sh
sudo dmidecode --type "Memory"
```

```sh
sudo dmidecode --type 17
```

- To see System Info, run one of these commands:

```sh
sudo dmidecode --type 1
```

```sh
sudo dmidecode --type "System"
```

If you only want to see OS info, run `lsb_release -a`

See more option about `dmidecode` type [here](https://www.linuxtechi.com/dmidecode-command-examples-linux/).

Comment: if i want get information in assembler and send this info to my GUI program, i should use only this terminal command?